# ASP.NET MVC 3 login page by using partial

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I want to use Logon page in on home page partially (which is index page).
Then my homepage has `UserName` textbox, `Password` textbox , `RememberMe` checkbox and button for login and register which means Logon page is partial view.

When I run the homepage and if I click Login button, it does not work validation error even 
I linked JavaScript and I put [Required] on model class.

I don't know how can I enable the validation error with JavaScript?

And how can I use the **HomeController**? (Homepage is default page)

Could you help me?

I am beginner, and I am just started to develop MVC application.

### Index.cshtml on Home folder

```
<div id="border_frame">
@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
</div>
```

### LogonPartial.cshtml on Shared folder

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.LogOnModel

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
<text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
[ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else
{
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { style = "width:150px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)

    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password,  new { style = "width:150px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) 
    <div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
    </div>
    <button name="button" class="login_button" value="logIn">Log In</button>
    <button name="button" class="register_button" value="register">Register now</button>
    </div>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
}
```

}

### AccountModel.cs

```
public class LogOnModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User ID")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

### HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a post action method to handle your postback.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LogonModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
         // do your validation stuff
    }

    // If you don't return the model, validation won't work.
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: If I put [httpPost] in HomeController, it has error because I think page cannot get any post value as starting page.. how do I have to do?

Comment: @wholee1 - you have two methods, a get and a post.